# TcpListener: How can I detect a client disconnect?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, tcpclient, tcplistener

How can I detect when a client disconnects from the TcpListener ?

Each of my clients is handled in a separate thread.

Comment: Might be worth retagging this as just [.net] instead of [C#] and [vb.net] since this has more to do with the framework instead of both languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [NetworkStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx), or depending on what you are using in your code maybe [TCPClient.GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx) is more appropriate, but basically the same answer.

From the docs:

> This method reads data into the buffer
>   parameter and returns the number of
>   bytes successfully read. If no data is
>   available for reading, the Read method
>   returns 0. The Read operation reads as
>   much data as is available, up to the
>   number of bytes specified by the size
>   parameter. **If the remote host shuts
>   down the connection, and all available
>   data has been received, the Read
>   method completes immediately and
>   return zero bytes.**