# TcpListener: Detecting a client disconnect as opposed to a client not sending any data for a while

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I was looking how to detect a 'client disconnect' when using a TcpListener.

All the answers seem to be similar to this one:
[TcpListener: How can I detect a client disconnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202154/tcplistener-how-can-i-detect-a-client-disconnect)

Basically, read from the stream and if Read() returns 0 the client had disconnected.

But that's assuming that a client disconnects after every single stream of data it sent.
We operate in environments where the TCP connect/disconnect overhead is both slow and expensive.

We establish a connection and then we send a number of requests.

Pseudocode:

```
client.Connect();
client.GetStatus();
client.DoSomething();
client.DoSomethingElse();
client.AndSoOn();
client.Disconnect();
```

Each call between Connect and Disconnect() sends a stream of data to the server.
The server knows how to analyze and process the streams.

If let the TcpListener read in a loop without ever disconnecting it reads and handles all the messages, but after the client disconnects, the server has no way of knowing that and 
it will never release the client and accept new ones.

```
var read = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

if (read > 0) 
{
   //Process
}
```

If I let the TcpListener drop the client when read == 0 it only accepts
the first stream of data only to drop the client immediately after.

Of course this means new clients can connect.

There is no artificial delay between the calls,
but in terms of computer time the time between two calls is 'huge' of course,
so there will always be a time when read == 0 even though that does not mean
the client has or should be disconnected.

```
var read = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

if (read > 0) 
{
   //Process
}
else
{
   break;   //Always executed as soon as the first stream of data has been received
}
```

So I'm wondering... is there a better way to detect if the client has disconnected?

Comment: Using something similar to `socket = listener.AcceptSocket(); s = new NetworkStream(socket); if (s.Read(..) == 0) ClientDisconnected();` appears to work fine for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the underlying socket using the `NetworkStream.Socket` property and use it's [Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5.aspx) method for reading.

Unlike `NetworkStream.Read`, the linked overload of `Socket.Receive` will block until the specified number of bytes have been read, and will only return zero if the remote host shuts down the TCP connection.

---

**UPDATE:** @jrh's comment is correct that `NetworkStream.Socket` is a protected property and cannot be accessed in this context. In order to get the client `Socket`, you could use the [TcpListener.AcceptSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which returns the `Socket` object corresponding to the newly established connection.

Comment: NetworkStream.Socket is not exposed byte the instance of NetworkStream returned by TcpListener.GetStream(). But I'm now looking into using the Socket class directly

Comment: Ok, using the sockets directly and using the Receive method works like a charm. A try catch is needed when Accepting the client and when trying to receive. Thnx !

Comment: Why doesn't .NET give you access to `NetworkStream.Socket` when it gives near unrestricted access to `TcpClient`'s socket through the `Client` property? Is this just a .NET design quirk, or is there a scenario where it makes sense to not be able to get a `NetworkStream`'s socket? Also you might want to revise this answer because `NetworkStream.Socket` is protected and not accessible.

Comment: @jrh you're right about the protected property, I've updated the answer. Most likely, NetworkStream doesn't give direct access to the Socket because it provides the ability to restrict reads and writes. See the [constructor overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) with FileAccess parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Eren's answer solved the problem for me. In case anybody else is facing the same issue
here's some 'sample' code using the Socket.Receive method:

```
private void AcceptClientAndProcess()
{
    try
    {
        client = server.Accept();
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 20000;
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int read = 0;

        try
        {
            read = client.Receive(buffer);
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }

        if (read > 0)
        {
            //Handle data
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (client != null)
        client.Close(5000);
}
```

You call AcceptClientAndProcess() in a loop somewhere.

The following line:

```
read = client.Receive(buffer);
```

will block until either

- Data is received, (read > 0) in which case you can handle it
- The connection has been closed properly (read = 0)
- The connection has been closed abruptly (An exception is thrown)

Either of the last two situations indicate the client is no longer connected.

The try catch around the Socket.Accept() method is also required
as it may fail if the client connection is closed abruptly during the connect phase.

Note that did specify a 20 second timeout for the read operation.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for `NetworkStream.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) does not reflect this, but in my experience, 'NetworkStream.Read' blocks if the port is still open and no data is available, but returns 0 if the port has been closed.

I ran into [this problem from the other side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719256/networkstream-read-is-blocking/), in that `NetworkStream.Read` does not immediately return 0 if no data is currently available.  You have to use `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` to find out if `NetworkStream.Read` can read data right now.