# NetworkStream callback called multiple times on server when client closes connection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm writing a simulator to test (de-)serialization of objects and sending them over TCP.
I use TcpClient, TcpListener and NetworkStreams in C# to communicate.
I want to open a connection, send multiple messages and after some time close the connection.
Establishing a connection and sending packets in both directions works fine.
However when i close the connection on the client (call `stream.Close()` and `tcpClient.Close()`) the server's callback for BeginRead is called again and again.

The client code:

```
private TcpClient client;

public void StartClient()
{
    this.client = new TcpClient(this.serverAddress, this.port);
}

public void Send(byte[] data)
{
    var stream = this.client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

public void StopClient()
{
    this.client.GetStream().Close();
    this.tcpClient.Close();
}
```

The server code:

```
private readonly AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent= new AutoResetEvent(false);

private TcpListener tcpListener;

public event Action<byte[]> MessageReceived;

public void StartListening()
{
    this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1337);
    this.tcpListener.Start();
    this.tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(this.ClientConnecting, this.tcpListener);
}

private void ClientConnecting(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var listener = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;

    this.tcpClient = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
    this.Listen();
}

private void Listen()
{
    var stream = this.tcpClient.GetStream();
    var buffer = new byte[256];
    while (stream.CanRead)
    {
        try
        {
            stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, this.DataReceiveCallback, new ReceiveState { Buffer = buffer, Stream = stream });
        }
        catch
        {
            this.StopListening();
            break;
        }

        this.autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
}

public void StopListening()
{
    var stream = this.tcpClient.GetStream();
    stream.Close();

    this.tcpClient.Close();
    this.tcpClient = null;
}

private void DataReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var state = (ReceiveState)ar.AsyncState;
    var stream = state.Stream;

    if (stream.CanRead)
    {
        var buffer = state.Buffer;
        var numberOfBytesRead = stream.EndRead(ar);

        if (this.MessageReceived != null)
        {
            if (!stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                this.MessageReceived(buffer.Take(numberOfBytesRead).ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                var receivedBytes = new List<byte>(buffer);
                while (stream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    receivedBytes.AddRange(buffer.Take(numberOfBytesRead));
                }
                this.MessageReceived(receivedBytes.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    this.autoResetEvent.Set();
}
```

When I call `StopClient()` on the client, the callback (`DataReceiveCallback`) on the server is being invoked. `stream.CanRead` returns true, but there are 0 bytes to read. Also `stream.DataAvailable` is false.

However, apart from that, I see no way to know on the server side, that the client closed the connection. And it is possible to receive 0 bytes from the client when the connection is still open.

What happens as af now, is that after closing the connection on the client, `DataReceiveCallback` is called again and again, always with 0 bytes to read.

What I want to do is close the connection on the server if the client closes the connection. What can I do to achieve this?

**Note**: I know that this example lacks proper error handling and you shouldn't start reading synchronously once you read something until the `stream.Read()` returns 0. However, this suits my needs for now as I directly control all the data being sendt.

Comment: _"it is possible to receive 0 bytes from the client when the connection is still open"_ - that's the `NetworkStream` abstraction for you. See [TcpListener: Detecting a client disconnect as opposed to a client not sending any data for a while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662598/tcplistener-detecting-a-client-disconnect-as-opposed-to-a-client-not-sending-an).

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at Socket.Receive()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling BeginRead in a loop. If the stream is done the read completes immediately with 0 bytes and the loop continues.

Your use of async IO makes no sense because you are blocking a thread waiting for the IO to complete. Undoubtedly, you have copied that from bad MSDN samples (without understanding what this does, really).

Throw that away and use a normal loop for reading synchronously. When the read call returns 0 you break the loop.

Also note, that TCP does not support messages in any way which you seem to assume right now. Delete all usages of `CanRead` and `DataAvailable`. As long as you are thinking in terms of these properties you are most likely doing it wrong.

Comment: I still don't understand why the callback is being invoked again and again, since normally it only springs to life when there is data available.
The server runs in its own thread. I use the asynchronous methods in combination with the AutoReset event because I want the thread to be blocked until there is new data available.
Using NetworkStream.Read() it wouldn't block but return 0 bytes aswell instantly if there was no data available. I would have to call Read() again and again to check if there was data available, but I want to avoid busy waiting.

Comment: No, NetworkStream.Read blocks until there is at least one byte. If it returns 0 the connection has been shut down by the remote side. Use NetworkStream.Read. Your elaborate scheme is not necessary.

Comment: You are totally right. I misinterpreted the documentation of NetworkStream.Read. Thank you!!